# In SONAR static code analyzer how to clean database weekly once?

Tags: database, static, sonarqube, analyzer

we are using SONAR(version:3.7.4) as static code analyzer and we want database to used by SONAR to be cleaned once in a week. I have set all database cleanup value ti minimum but still it database is not cleaned once in a week .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sh7q.jpg)

Regards,
Prem

Answer (score 0):

- please update your version of [SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/). You're missing a lot of features regarding the platform or the language analyzers
- the database cleanup is executed at the end of a project analysis with the database cleaner parameters given